# How do I create a class with constants as parameters in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

in the XNA framework for example there is a `SpriteBatch` Class. The `SpriteBatch.Begin()` method accepts parameters like this:

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.FrontToBack, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
```

How can I create a class that accepts parameters in the same way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

create an [`Enum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
enum FooBarMode
{
     FrontToBack,
     BackToFront,
     Whatever
}
```

and use that as a parameter:

```
void DoSomething(FooBarMode mode)
{
    switch (mode) // just as an example
    {
        case FooBarMode.FrontToBack:
            Console.WriteLine("FrontToBack");
            break;
        case FooBarMode.BackToFront:
            Console.WriteLine("BackToFront");
            break;
        case FooBarMode.Whatever:
            Console.WriteLine("Whatever");
            break;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("mode");
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. Yes and (@MartijnBurger) Visual Studio creates the switch statement for you. Just type the beginning of the word "switch" (often "sw" is enough) and type <Tab> twice, enter a variable name in the placeholder and hit <Enter> and you get a nice switch-statement almost for free!

Answer (score 0):

The parameter types are enum (SpriteSortMode) and static fields (BlendState.AlphaBlend). The difference is on how complex the choice is. Use enums for simple choices and static fields when it's a bit more complex.